# How to set a fixed width column with CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the red box to be only 25 em wide when it's in the side-by-side view - I'm trying to achieve this by setting the CSS inside this media query:

```
@media all and (min-width: 811px) {...}
```

to:

```
.flexbox .red {
  width: 25em;
}
```

But when I do that, this happens:

[image]CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPNpaP.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 648, accepted):

I'd recommend to use `flex/flex-basis` properties rather than `width/height`.

```
.flexbox .red {
  flex: 0 0 25em;
}
```

The `flex` CSS property is a shorthand property specifying the ability of a flex item to alter its dimensions to fill available space. It contains:

```
flex-grow: 0;     /* do not grow   - initial value: 0 */
flex-shrink: 0;   /* do not shrink - initial value: 1 */
flex-basis: 25em; /* width/height  - initial value: auto */
```

A simple demo below shows how to set the first column to `50px` fixed width.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox > div {
  outline: 1px solid;
}
.red {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  color: red;
}
.green {
  flex: 1;
  color: green;
}
.blue {
  flex: 1;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="red">1</div>
  <div class="green">2</div>
  <div class="blue">3</div>
</div>
```

**More info**

Let's say flex-direction is set to row (default value):

- flex-basis overrides width if specifically declared anything other than flex-basis: auto (default value).
- with flex-basis: auto (or not specified), it first checks for width, if none, it uses the elements content width.
- flex-basis still obeys max-width & min-width.

The sizing follows this formula:

```
content —> width —> flex-basis (limited by max-width & min-width)
```

Same thing for flex-direction: column, height, max-height, and min-height.

I think it is best to practice using flex-basis over width/height, this way the results are always consistent.

Comment: The parent has `display: flex;` and the child you want to set the width for has `flex-grow: 0;`, `flex-shrink: 0;` and `width: 300px;// or 20em or what have you`

Answer (score 17):

In case anyone wants to have a responsive flexbox with percentages (%) it is much easier for media queries.

```
flex-basis: 25%;
```

This will be a lot smoother when testing.

```
// VARIABLES
$screen-xs:                                         480px;
$screen-sm:                                         768px;
$screen-md:                                         992px;
$screen-lg:                                         1200px;
$screen-xl:                                         1400px;
$screen-xxl:                                        1600px;

// QUERIES
@media screen (max-width: $screen-lg) {
    flex-basis: 25%;
}

@media screen (max-width: $screen-md) {
    flex-basis: 33.33%;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually, if you really want to use the width CSS property another workaround for this is to apply this:

```css
.flexbox .red {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 25em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.flexbox .red {
  width: min(25em, 100%)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).