# Why does inline-block in css generate weird spacing issues?

Tags: css

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/dm05xe9y/

I want to understand why the div wasn't able to wrap around the inline-block elements (buttons in this case).

html

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="first">First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First Firsta</div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <button>Hello</button>
    <button>Hey</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.first {
  margin-right: auto;
}
.wrap {
  background: #833;
}
```

EDIT: you need to max size the browser portion to see the red spacing on the right.

Comment: Inline-block treats an element similarly like text. If there are spaces in your element(even if that is a new line) it will be treated like space.

Comment: there is no inline block in your code and no space

Answer (score 0):

The browser is left to make that determination for flexbox elements.

Try changing the width of the window and see how it changes.

This post might help you. [How to set a fixed width column with CSS flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885284/how-to-set-a-fixed-width-column-with-css-flexbox/29885495)

Comment: shouldn't flex box just resize and squeeze the empty space out of the red container as well?

Comment: Well, it's also trying to fill the width of the browser window. You just need to give it the necessary information. In this case, if you say `flex-basis:0px;` it will start out rendering zero width and expand to accommodate the content.

Answer (score 0):

add `<br>` between button or set `display:block` to button

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.wrap {
  background: #833;
}

.wrap button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="first">First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First Firsta</div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <button>Hello</button>
    <button>Hey</button>
  </div>
</div>
```