# How to prevent child div from resize?

Tags: css

The height of my parent div is fixed and i need to add multiple child div which could be scrolled through due to overflow. I have used flex layout to arrange  child div in one column.

The issue i am facing is that, the child div(s) are resizing themselves to adjust inside the
parent div instead of maintaing their height and introducing scroll bar.

I have tried `resize: none;`, but that didn't worked.

Code is as follows :

Html code :

```
<div id="parent-box">
        <div class="child-box"></div>
        <div class="child-box"></div>
        <div class="child-box"></div>
        <div class="child-box"></div>
        <div class="child-box"></div>
</div>
```

Css code :

```
#parent-box{
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: auto;
}
.child-box {
    height: 100px; 
    margin: 10px;
    resize: none;
}
```

I have tried finding the solution but didn't got one, since i didn't knew exactly what to search. Please share any article or documentation related to this concept.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding  flex: 0 0 25%   this property in child element

```css
#parent-box{
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: auto;
    background: red;
}
.child-box {
    height: 100px; 
    margin: 10px;
    resize: none;
    background: yellow;  
    flex: 0 0 100px;
}
```

```html
   <div id="parent-box">
        <div class="child-box"></div>
        <div class="child-box"></div>
        <div class="child-box"></div>
        <div class="child-box"></div>
        <div class="child-box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the flex or flex-basis property rather than width. Like this:

```
.child-box {  
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
```

equivalent to:

```
flex-grow: 0;      /* do not grow   - initial value: 0 */
flex-shrink: 0;    /* do not shrink - initial value: 1 */
flex-basis: 100px; /* width/height  - initial value: auto */
```

You can read more about it here: [How to set a fixed width column with CSS flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885284/how-to-set-a-fixed-width-column-with-css-flexbox)